# Objective-C enums conform to RawRepresentable

Tags: swift, rawrepresentable

Any exprerience on this I have for example the following enum written in objc

```
typedef enum {
  Type1,
  Type2
} Type;

extension Type: RawRepresentable {
    typealias RawValue = UInt32
}
```

compiler crashes when I'm trying to conform to RawRepresentable.The only thing that I can imaging is that RawRepresentable works only with swift enums.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget about using raw C enum and use the Objective-C `NS_ENUM` macro:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnumType) {
    Type1,
    Type2
};
```

Then in Swift the enum will be already `RawRepresentable`. You cannot add that conformance this way. Well, you probably could, but you will have to also declare `init?(rawValue:)` and `var rawValue`.